# Google App Engine - Get from repeated StructuredProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have the following structures:

```
class UserOther(ndb.Model):
    other_type = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = True)
    other_data = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = False)

class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(default = "NULL", indexed = False) 
    email = ndb.StringProperty(default = "NULL", indexed = False) 
    active = ndb.BooleanProperty(default = True)

    others = ndb.StructuredProperty(UserOther, repeated = True)
    updated_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
```

How can I use an User key id and a string for other_type(like "job") to get and be able to edit that information. I tried using the ancestor parameter, but perhaps I didn't do that correctly.

```
user_key = ndb.Key("User", user_id)
user = user_key.get()
other = UserOther.query(UserOther.other_type == "job", ancestor = user_key).get()
```

So if i print my user looks like this :

```
1425436064.0User(key=Key('User', 5171003185430528), active=True, email=u'NULL', name=u'NULL', others=[UserOther(other_data=u'0', other_type=u'job'), UserOther(other_data=u'0', other_type=u'times_worked'), UserOther(other_data=u'0', other_type=u'times_opened')], updated_at=datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 10, 35, 24, 838078))
```

But if I print the job variable it is

```
 1425436759.0None
```

Comment: sorry, it was a wrong copy paste. I edited, and i'll do that in a second with more information too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is get the user (by id) and then filter the 'others' in code:

```
user = User.get_by_id(user_key_id)
for other in user.others:
    if other.other_type == 'job':
        print other.other_data  # do edits
```

Comment: Ok, i thought about that too. I hoped there is a way to query, since google is suggesting in it's tutorial to use this instead of separate entities. SIlly google.

Comment: Well you can query by those values just as any (as mentioned in the other answer), I'm just saying that this is what I would do in your case, since you have the id and getting by key is very efficient. Now, if there are that many nested entities that you want to get a subset, it makes much more sense to me to store them as independent entities (with user as ancestor).

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood how to query for structured properties. The UserOther entity doesn't live on its own, it's part of the relevant User entity, so that's what you need to query.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties) explains exactly how to do this, but in summary you would do:

```
job = User.query(User.others.other_type == "job").get()
```

Comment: and how do I do that for a specific user with it's key?

Comment: Just like you are doing, but you don't then query inside that; you just do `user.others` which gives you a list of UserOther instances.

Comment: I don't really get how to use the user variable that i have in order to query jobs through it

Comment: I think you must have a wrong impression of what structured properties are. They're for storing a small number of linked entities *as a part* of the parent entity. You can't query them separately, because they're not separate. You can either query for a User by its jobs, or get one user and show all its jobs, but you can't query a job directly.

Comment: Then why on earth the documentation google provided suggested it's a better approach to store data like this if I can't f***ing query it.

Comment: also, the query you provided is invalid